# Why doesn't Agent 33 take off her mask in Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. season 2?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

So, I'm midway through watching the second season of Agents of SHIELD on Netflix, and one of the Hydra agents (referred to as Agent 33) disguises herself as Agent May early on in the season.

But even after she's discovered and her face is partially burned (or something), she continues to wear the mask that she wore as her "Agent May" disguise. Why? I didn't quite follow that part, and I'm not sure what's keeping her from taking the mask off. Was it fused to her face or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exactly, the mask was damaged in fight, and something as micro chips are fused to her face, and now she can't take the mask off, without get hurt.